# validar inserción de datos en laravel con registros de la base de datos

Tags: php, sql, laravel, base-de-datos

Tengo esta función en un controlador que me permite ingresar 8 registros.

Cómo podría validar que solo se pueda registrar estos 8 registros solo una vez por cada usuario a un psicólogo.

[image: funcion de insertar]

Les dejo una foto de la base de datos en la que están los 8 registros.

La idea es que se caiga si coinciden el userId, psicologoId y el tipoValoracion_idTipo que sería al ingresar nuevamente los registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué no validas al inicio, antes del foreach? Simplemente buscas si hay registros en tu tabla con ese id de usuario y psicólogo. Si hay entonces no insertas, caso contrario sí.

Comment: @L.Flor Como sería la parte para comprobar si existe o no?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un chequeo antes de procesar el `for` con los INSERT.

Suponiendo que userId es el identificador del usuario y numeroPsicologo el del psicologo, debes chequear si existen registros con ambos identificadores:

```
$existe = Valoracion::where([
    ['user_id', '=', $request->input('userId')],
    ['numero_psicologo', '=', $request->input('numeroPsicologo')]
  ])->first();
if ($existe === null) {
   // par no ha sido registrado antes, proceder con for/insert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue la solución, gracias @F.Igor

```
public function insertarValo(Request $request){
        for($z=1;$z<=8;$z++){
            $uid = $request->input('userId');
            $pid = $request->input('numeroPsicologo');
            $existe = Valoracion::where([
                ['userId', '=', $uid],
                ['psicologoId', '=', $pid],
                ['tipoValoracion_idTipo', '=', $z]
              ])->first();
            if ($existe === null) {
                $addVal = new Valoracion();
                $addVal->userId = $request->input('userId');
                $addVal->psicologoId = $request->input('numeroPsicologo');
                $addVal->rating = $request->input('rating'.$z);
                $addVal->tipoValoracion_idTipo = $z;
                $addVal->save();
            }
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```